# CSS vertical align text in div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Regarding https://jsfiddle.net/postiffm/74cxr092/

```
> <div id="Tagline">
>     I'm in the center.
>     <div id="TaglineLeft"></div>
>     <div id="TaglineRight"><a href="tel:1-734-123-4567">I am a phone #</a></div> </div>
```

How can I align the text in the TaglineRight so it has some space above it like the text in the center section? I've tried some padding and margin stuff, but nothing seems to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

add line-height:30px; to #TaglineRight a

Comment: This was the simplest solution. Thanks! Worked great.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of playing around with position:absolute/relative. 
Consider using display:flex

check this solution

```css
#Tagline {
  color: white;
  font-weight: normal;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 0 solid #ff9706;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-color: #ff9706;
  display: flex;
  height:30px;
    line-height: 30px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
#TaglineLeft,
#TaglineRight {
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  border-radius: 7px;
  text-align: center;

}
#TaglineLeft {

  margin-top: 0px;
  background-color: #6673aa;
  order: -1;

}
#TaglineRight {
  border: 0 solid #7e922e;
  background-color: #7e922e;
}
#TaglineRight a {
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="Tagline">
  I'm in the center.
  <div id="TaglineLeft">left line</div>
  <div id="TaglineRight"><a href="tel:1-123-123-1234">I am a phone #</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Almost works, and I learned a bit about the flex directive. However, it shows an orange border around the blue and green, which was not what I wanted. Thanks for your time. I appreciate it.

Comment: Accept Connor's solution that's the simplest and straight answer to your problem.but instead of playing with position's it is always good to use display:flex for layouts

Answer (score 1):

```
#TaglineLeft, #TaglineRight {
 position: absolute;
 color: white;
 font-weight: normal;
 text-align: center;
 height: 100%;
 width: 30%;
 top: 0;
 border-radius: 7px;
 height: 20px;
 padding: 5px;
}
```

you may add  **height: 20px;** and **padding: 5px;** to **#TaglineLeft, #TaglineRight {** class

Comment: Sorry. Actually this solution does work https://jsfiddle.net/postiffm/74cxr092/5/ does work, but only if the height: 20px and padding: 5px are AFTER the height: 100% statement.

Answer (score 1):

an old fashion way is to treat the child element as an table data by set it to `display: table-cell`, `vertical-align: middle;` & set it's parent to `display: table;`.
in that way you can change the height of the parent to whatever/whenever you like to and the child element will always stay vertical aligned. not like CSS3 solutions, it will work in old browsers too and cross browser support of course.
https://jsfiddle.net/ryf0w7rp/ - try to change the "#Tagline" element's height from 20px to other value and see the result.

*if you don't want main wrapper elements to use `display: table` so you can create another level of element to use `display: table`.

*for the example i made the solution just for the "#TaglineRight" element which has an inner `<a>` element. to make the other elements work the same, add the same structure and set the CSS to the right elements.